# .NET Socket DisconnectAsync Task extension method

Tags: .net, sockets, task, disconnect

Microsoft provides a [`SocketTaskExtensions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.sockettaskextensions.connectasync?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Sockets_SocketTaskExtensions_ConnectAsync_System_Net_Sockets_Socket_System_Net_EndPoint_) class that provides extension methods to use the Task asynchronous programming paradigm. However, this class does not provide a `Task DisconnectAsync` method. I imagine there is a reason for that but I can't figure it out.

The [`System.Net.Sockets.Socket`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket?view=netframework-4.8) class does provide a [`DisconnectAsync(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.disconnectasync?view=netframework-4.8) but it does not return a Task.

I am about to implement the extension method by myself but I'm wondering if there's something I am missing here.

Thanks in advance!

### Edit

I have opened [an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1608) and this is being worked on as of October 28 2020

Comment: AFAIK, I believe the only way to achieve this is to create your own wrapper method that will return a Task. Maybe someone will come up with a better idea so I won't answer yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am about to implement the extension method by myself but I'm wondering if there's something I am missing here.

We just haven't got to it yet.

It's not a common API for people to need, so the `Task` version hasn't been a big priority. The existing `DisconnectAsync` provides all the needed functionality, but is just a little harder to use.

Feel free to file an issue on our Github repo with the suggested API.

Comment: Thanks for the straightforward answer! Just to be certain though, which GitHub repository would that be?

Comment: .NET Core is on Github; feature suggestions should go there: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues